# R array solution to updating all instances of a value based on a flag in one field

Tags: r, arrays, dataframe

Is there a SAS-type array method in R whereby I could change all N/A values in any of the fields based on the "not_miss" field being != (not equal to) "0"?
not_miss field was created by summing the non N/As DF2["not_miss"] <- as.character(rowSums(DF2 == "1" | DF2 == "0")) this code doesn't need to run again. the dataframe below is complete.

```
DF2 <- 
data.frame(Drug_Intake_Heroin=c('N/A','0','0','N/A','1','1','N/A'),
          Drug_Intake_Fentanyl=c('N/A','0','0','N/A','1','1','N/A'),
          Drug_Intake_Cocaine =c('N/A','1','0','N/A','0','1','1'),
           Drug_Intake_Crack = c('N/A','0','1','1','1','0','N/A'),
            not_miss = c('0','4','4','1','4','4','1'))
```

This works but can the fields be treated as a SAS-type arrary?

#1 Heroin

```
DF2$Drug_Intake_Heroin <- ifelse((DF2$Drug_Intake_Heroin == "N/A" & DF2$not_miss != "0"), "0",  DF2$Drug_Intake_Heroin)
```

#2 Fentanyl

```
DF2$Drug_Intake_Fentanyl <- ifelse((DF2$Drug_Intake_Fentanyl == "N/A" & DF2$not_miss != "0"), "0",  DF2$Drug_Intake_Fentanyl)
```

#3 Cocaine

```
DF2$Drug_Intake_Cocaine <- ifelse((DF2$Drug_Intake_Cocaine == "N/A" & DF2$not_miss != "0"), "0",  DF2$Drug_Intake_Cocaine)
```

#4 Crack

```
DF2$Drug_Intake_Crack <- ifelse((DF2$Drug_Intake_Crack == "N/A" & DF2$not_miss != "0"), "0",  DF2$Drug_Intake_Crack)
```

How can this operation be written as a function or loop and then be expressed as a plyr operation?

```
 DF2 <- DF2 %>% 
            mutate_at(
                    c("Drug_Intake_Heroin","Drug_Intake_Fentanyl",
                      "Drug_Intake_Cocaine","Drug_Intake_Crack"),  
                    funs(case_when(. == "N/A" & DF2$not_miss != "0" 
                     ~ "0", TRUE ~ "N/A")))
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Welcome to SO, MasterG! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Two things stand out in your code: (1) `function(x) =` is invalid, perhaps just remove the `=` from that? (2) `DF2[] != "0"` might make sense elsewhere, but inside the anon-function in an `lapply(..)`, this seems out of place. Perhaps you meant `!x %in% c("N/A", "0")`? (3) `x == True` only works if there is a predefined object named `True`, don't confuse spelled-like "true" with R's constant `TRUE`. These are just a few points, it'd be much easier to help with sample data. Good luck!

Comment: okay, I will add some data. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a current `dplyr` version of your code:

```
library(dplyr)
DF2 |>
  mutate(across(
    starts_with("Drug_Intake"),
    \(x) ifelse(x == "N/A" & not_miss != "0", "0", x)
  ))
#   Drug_Intake_Heroin Drug_Intake_Fentanyl Drug_Intake_Cocaine Drug_Intake_Crack not_miss
# 1                N/A                  N/A                 N/A               N/A        0
# 2                  0                    0                   1                 0        4
# 3                  0                    0                   0                 1        4
# 4                  0                    0                   0                 1        1
# 5                  1                    1                   0                 1        4
# 6                  1                    1                   1                 0        4
# 7                  0                    0                   1                 0        1
```

Comment: not_miss is the number of non N/As in the row. the purpose of the program is to convert N/A to 0 if the not_miss field is not equal to 0, meaning that there was at least 1 non N/A value in the row. in your example data, you failed to include the "0" value for not_miss in the first row.  DF2["not_miss"] <- as.character(rowSums(DF2 == "1" | DF2 == "0"))

Comment: Oh, I just ran the code from your question, `DF2["not_miss"] <- as.character(rowSums(DF2 == "1" | DF2 == "0"))`, which gives `1` in the first row. But I see now that you set it explicitly to `0`. I'll update.

Comment: Oh, and it only gave `1` for the first row because I ran the subsequent definition of `DF2` first, which had a `0` for `not_miss` in the first row. A circular error.

Comment: Yes, I included the code to show how not_miss was calculated. I'll change that.

Comment: Thanks, @Gregor Thomas. That worked perfectly, but why do we have to escape \(x)?

Comment: `\(x)` is a shorthand for `function(x)` introduced in version 4 a couple years ago.